# Cannot make mod_gzip

Tags: compression, apache-2.2

I am trying to compile mod_gzip to my Apache 2.2.22 setup. I get the following error when running `make`:

```
$ make
/usr/sbin/apxs -Wc,-Wall,-O3,-fomit-frame-pointer,-pipe -c mod_gzip.c mod_gzip_debug.c mod_gzip_compress.c -o mod_gzip.so
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=compile gcc -prefer-pic -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic  -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -pthread -I/usr/include/httpd  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -Wall,-O3,-fomit-frame-pointer,-pipe  -c -o mod_gzip.lo mod_gzip.c && touch mod_gzip.slo
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wall,-O3,-fomit-frame-pointer,-pipe'
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

Can anyone please advise on how to handle this?

Comment: Use the packages instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this bit "-Wall,-O3,-fomit-frame-pointer,-pipe" should have the commas in it. Not sure where they came from, but you might try getting rid of them.

Comment: It came from the Makefile included with the source code. I initially had the same hunch and removed the commas, but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: What's the new error?